# Limitar tamanho do upload com PHP

Tags: php

Configurei o ***php.ini*** e alterei o tamanho máximo permitido para upload de 12MB.

No PHP, limitei o tamanho do upload também a 12MB, da seguinte forma:

```
if($_FILES['imagem']['size']>12582912){
   echo "Limite máximo 12 MB!"; 
   //...
}
```

O problema é se tentar fazer upload de um ficheiro com mais de 12MB, não mostra o erro e simplesmente não faz nada.

Se alterar o ***php.ini*** e aumentar o limite para 1GB (por exemplo) e só na aplicação limitar a 12MB, assim já funciona se tentar enviar um ficheiro com mais de 12MB, aparece a mensagem de erro.

Porque o erro não aparece quando limito tudo a 12MB (php.ini e o script) e tento fazer um upload com mais de 12MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando um arquivo enviado ultrapassa o valor definido no `post_max_size`, o PHP não dispara erro, ele simplesmente envia um `$_POST` vazio, há uma maneira de detectar se o arquivo ultrapassa o valor definido no `post_max_size`.

```
if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) 
    && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //pega o erro de tamanho maximo excedido

        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //pega limite máximo
        echo "Arquivo enviado excede: $postMax"; // exibe o erro
}
else {// continua com o processamento da página

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "<pre/>";
}
```

**Solução encontrada em:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size