# Limitar tamanho do upload com PHP para mais de um arquivo

Tags: php

Supondo que existe um único array na variável `$_FILES`, o código abaixo limita o tamanho de upload de um arquivo:

```
if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) 
    && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //pega o erro de tamanho maximo excedido

        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //pega limite máximo
        echo "Arquivo enviado excede: $postMax"; // exibe o erro
}
else {// continua com o processamento da página

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "<pre/>";
}
```

Contudo, possuo mais de um array do tipo `file`, ou seja: `$_FILES['logotipo']` e `$_FILES['certificado']`. Como faria para ajustar a resposta, ou fazer essa limitação individualmente para cada arquivo?

Referência:  [Limitar tamanho do upload com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21091/31236)

Comment: Se eu não me engano, se colocar `ini_get('post_max_size'); ` no topo do arquivo, ele pega para todos... não tenho certeza

Comment: no SOe: (Em inglês) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6576751/6510304

Comment: Cada item do array do `file` terá o campo `["size"]=> int()`. O que você precisa seria validar de formas diferentes para os `$_FILES['logotipo']` e `["size"]=> int(76928)`?

Comment: Olá @DNick, a questão é que o campo `size` só será preenchido caso o arquivo não exceda o limite, e não quero ter que configurar o **php.ini** pra isso.

Comment: Olá @Everson, cai no mesmo caso e sugestão do DNick.

Comment: @MagicHat,  mas o que teria que fazer após isso? Pois, ele pegou simplesmente o valor **8M**, sendo que o limite é só **2M** e o arquivo que estou passando é **2.5M** (o que já faz com que  `size` fique com o valor zero).